# Create conditional based upon current year when looping through records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to show `Date.current.year` if there are no @past_challenges with a `:deadline` set for `Date.current.year`.

### Controller

```
@past_challenges = current_user.challenges.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline < Date.current if challenge.deadline.present? }
@past_challenges_by_years = @past_challenges.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_year }
```

### Attempt

```
<% if @past_challenges_by_years[Date.today.year] ||= [ ] %>
  <h2>2016</h2>
<% end %>
```

The above didn't work because 2016 is duplicated. Once as part of the `group_by` and the other as part of the conditional. I only want the conditional to trigger if `@past_challenges` has no challenges with a `t.date :deadline` == `Date.current.year`. This will mean there should always be just one listing of the current year.

[image]

Comment: The conditional in your view is always going to be truthy: `<% if @past_challenges_by_years[Date.today.year] ||= [ ] %>`

Comment: @maxpleaner is there a way I can rewrite it where it is true only if a past challenge has a deadline for `Date.current.year`?

Comment: I think you are using `||=` where you want to use `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems. One is that you're grouping your challenges by `t.deadline.beginning_of_year`, which is something like `2016-01-01 00:00:00 -0800`, then pulling from your hash using `Date.today.year`, which is just `2016`. You can use whichever of the two methods you prefer, you just have to be consistent. I'd recommend `.year`, since it's simpler and seems more semantic.

Meantime, `@past_challenges_by_years[Date.today.year]` is always going to be `nil`, and then you `||= []`, leaving it always an empty array and leading to the second problem: empty arrays are truthy. Now your check always passes, and you always render 2016. You can fix the existing code by checking `@past_challenges_by_years[Date.today.year].nil?` to see if there's an entry at all, but you can remove some complexity from your view if you make some more guarantees about your hash:

```
@past_challenges_by_years = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
@past_challenges.each { |c| @past_challenges_by_years[c.deadline.year] << c }
```

`Hash.new`'s block ensures that any key every looked up will be initialized with an empty array, so you won't have to worry about `nil`s where you don't want them. Then in your view, you don't need to check whether there's a 2016 entry or special case the current year at all, you just render whichever years you want:

```
<%- 2016.downto(2010).each do |year| -%>
  <h2><%= year %></h2>
  <ul>
  <%- @past_challenges_by_year[year].each do |challenge| -%>
    <li><%= challenge.name %></li>
  <%- end -%>
  </ul>
<%- end -%>
```

Comment: With your code controller code chunk you offered I'm getting `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`, which I tried addressing with `@past_challenges.each { |c| @past_challenges_by_years[c.deadline.year] << c if c.deadline.present?  }` but it didn't work